# mysql update columns remove last word

Tags: mysql, sql-update

How to perform an `UPDATE` on a whole varchar column by removing the last word?

Every row has a value like `one two three lastword` `one two lastword` `one lastword` (there is no row with value just `lastword`). Fortunately, all words are separated by 1 space. I want the `lastword` removed (and its preceding space character) for the whole table

`lastword` is not a unique word, i used this just for example. every row has its own last word, (so i cannot just replace `'lastword'` with `''`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the column you're talking about is called `col1`:

```
UPDATE table SET col1=RTRIM(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(col1),LOCATE(" ",REVERSE(col1)))))
```

Comment: aha! *"LOCATE: Return the position of the **first** occurrence of substring"* exactly where i was stuck. combine this with some REVERSE and SUBSTRING and it works :D Thank you!

Comment: Will this need a trim afterwards?

Comment: Ah, good point, my version of MySQL doesn't trim spaces when storing varchars, so RTRIM() is necessary. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE `table_name` SET `col`=TRIM('last_word' FROM `col`) WHERE `col` REGEXP 'last_word$'

Comment: This would be OK if the final word was always `lastword.` However the OP said that they were just using that as an example and that the final word was not unique. Hence you cannot simply always trim off the string `lastword`. I know many questions on SO are not very clear but this one was and it's important to read questions carefully when answering.